# What do the parameters after “inset” mean in this CSS box-shadow syntax?

Tags: css

I came across a `box-shadow` attribute that was written with the following syntax:

```
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.24),inset 0 -22px rgba(23,49,76,0.03);
```

I followed the [w3s](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp) documentation for `box-shadow` and got what it mean until the bit after the `inset` argument. The additional parameters after `inset` aren't clarified there.

So, what is the meaning of these additional values?

```
0 -22px rgba(23,49,76,0.03)
```

Comment: It's documented here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#shadow-inset and here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#inset

Comment: Just in case you’re not clear on this (and you might well be, so apologies if this unnecessary), w3schools.com doesn’t really provide documentation, rather tutorials. [The official documentation for CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#box-shadow) is produced by [the W3C](http://www.w3.org/), an entirely separate organisation.

Comment: Opinion: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use. I recommend using the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) instead.

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters you describe are actually the offsets and colour of another `box-shadow`. The comma (`,`) in the value means two box shadows are being defined.

Some different indentation might make it clearer:

```
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.24),/* <-- Note the comma here, separating the two box shadows */
            inset 0 -22px rgba(23,49,76,0.03);
```

[The W3C’s `box-shadow` documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#box-shadow) ([which is more reliable than w3schools.com — w3schools is not linked with the W3C, despite their name](http://www.w3fools.com/)) mentions this:

> The ‘box-shadow’ property attaches one or more drop-shadows to the box. The property takes a comma-separated list of shadows

Comment: I really didn't know that w3schools.com is not linked with the W3C , so you very helped me :-)

Comment: @URL87: it’s a misleading name, isn’t it! You’re most welcome — I personally think their tutorials are nicely written, especially when you’re just beginning a given technology, but the “W3” in the name is confusing.